# How can I get a value from the JWT header into a variable in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, function, jwt

I am making an API server where I can login and see some information. Whenever I log in I get a JWT token which contains my username. I want to store this username in a variable whenever I want to use it. This is the code I use to verify my token when I want to enter certain webpages.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.header("access-token");
  
  if (!authHeader) return res.sendStatus(401);

  jwt.verify(authHeader, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
}

export default authenticateToken;
```

It checks if the header contains a JWT token. If so it verifies it. Then at the bottom the user gets retrieved, but I dont know how to get this value.

On my routes I secure them like this:

```
router.get("/", authenticateToken, getData);
```

within the getData method im displaying data from a mysql database. I want to add a check to see if my username is equal to the data in getData (since you can only see certain data).

In getData i get my data like this:

```
connection.query(
  "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid = ?", [user.username],
  (err, rows) =>
```

On the [user.username] spot I want to retrieve the username within the JWT token. I want to do this using a method, but I cant seem to get it. How can I get my username?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change your code a little bit to pass the `request` to the `getData` function, as you store the authenticated user within the `request`.

Try something like this:

```
router.get("/", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    getData(req);
});
```